# C++ read/write to array out of bounds

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

There's probably already an answer to this somewhere, but I can't find it.

As noted in this question: [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why), C++ does not enforce array bounds, instead opting to provide undefined behavior.  What I'm concerned about is the power of this behavior.

So suppose I write some simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int* a = new int[1];
    long large_number = 9223372036854775807l; //2**63 - 1
    for (long i = 0l; i < large_number; i++) {
        std::cout << i << " " << a[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will continue to print the next 32-bit number stored on my system (assuming 32 bit-sized ints, obviously).  When I run this on my machine, the program segfaults when i is around 30,000, which I'm guessing is around the size of the memory allocated for my program.  This brings me to my question, which is three-fold:

1. What's preventing me from continuing to read (not write) values outside this range?  Is this prevention of reading system-specific?  Compiler-specific?
2. If I was clever with how I manipulate my pointer, could I read or write values outside of the scope of my program (without, obviously, having direct/normal access to these values)?
3. I'm running all of this on a virtual machine.  Can I access read/write memory values on my host machine?  (If (2) is a no, then this is a no as well).

Note that I'm running g++ 5.3.1, no c++11, on a ubuntu virtualbox with a windows host machine.

Also, I recognize this question could be considered a security issue (reading/writing memory).  I'm certainly not intending anything malicious, but if this is a problem, let me know and I will be glad to close the question.

EDIT:  The following question appears related and interesting:
[Accessing outside the memory allocated by the program. (Accessing other app's memory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617586/accessing-outside-the-memory-allocated-by-the-program-accessing-other-apps-me)
There doesn't seem to be a consensus on whether or not a program can read outside of it's virtual memory space though.

Comment: Look up _virtual memory_. Each process in modern OS's has its own memory space, and the memory of other processes (or the host machine on a VM) are not visible.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Out of curiosity, do all modern OS's use virtual memory management?  Can you give a program access to information outside of its virtual memory space?  I can't find much of a consensus...

Comment: Unless you're the kernel (or there is a bug in the kernel's implementation), no - you don't have access to other programs' memory space in user mode.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by user mode?  If I run the program as a superuser (sudo), could I get access?  Do you mean user mode as opposed to kernel mode, as in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554836(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: If you're superuser, you can pretty much do whatever you want.  For example, under Linux the root user can read or write directly to physical RAM via the  /dev/mem device.  Good times!

Comment: Wow, that's kind of terrifying.  Good to know, thanks.

Comment: _Usermode_ or _userspace_ is the mode that programs run in. They usually run in a restricted environment (ex. can't access hardware or other process' memory directly) and must communicate with the OS. In contrast _kernelspace_ is the mode that the kernel runs in. It has full access to the hardware. (Root programs do _not_ execute in kernel mode; they are user mode apps where the OS will grant all permissions. Only kernel code can run in kernel mode)

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  So even with running code with sudo, there should be no way on a modern OS to manipulate data outside of your virtual machine since it isn't kernel code.  Fascinating, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. The operating system. The operating system mapped only a certain range of virtual addresses onto physical addresses. After reaching the end of the mapped virtual address ranges, an attempt to access a nonexistent virtual address generates a `SIGSEGV`.
2. No. At least not on any modern operating system.
3. Not unless you can find a bug in your host operating system's virtual machine, and exploit it.